# Trying to create a box

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a random amount of boxes dynamically with javascript. However, I am a little lost of how to do so. I thought I would try my hand at just trying to create boxes on the html first. So, here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Ramdom Boxes</title>
        <script src="A2Q1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div id="piece8" class="pieces" style="color:#0000ff; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 60px; height: 60px; cursor: pointer;"></div>

    <body>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Somehow the box isnt showing up. However when I inspect the element in the browser it seems to be there but no color. How do I fix this to make a simple 2d box show up

Comment: Your div needs to go within the body tags. Also please post the contents of A2Q1.js.

Comment: @j08691 that javascript file is a total mess... The idea is to dynamically create a random amount of boxes, of random colours, in random positions on the page. I thought I did it at first but I was just drawing objects on the canvas and not storing them anywhere. The boxes are to be moved around with mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

I supposed to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FHUeE/

and it's `background-color:#0000ff;` not `color:#0000ff;` `color` is for font color.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure all your content goes between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags.

Also you need to use the css property background-color if you want a colour to show up. color changes the text color:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Ramdom Boxes</title>
        <script src="A2Q1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>      
  <div id="piece8" class="pieces" style="background-color:#0000ff; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 60px; height: 60px; cursor: pointer;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might get you going:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FjrxA

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Random Boxes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
  // Make a loop to create a random amount of boxes
  var box_count = Math.random() * 100 + 50;
  for (var i = 0; i < box_count; i++) {
    // Define an array of css attributes
    var attr =[
      // Assign a colour to the box
      'background-color:#' + parseInt(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF, 10).toString(16),
      // Place the box somewhere inside the window
      'left:' + Math.random() * window.innerWidth + 'px',
      'top:' + Math.random() * window.innerHeight + 'px',
      // Give the box a random size
      'width:' + Math.random() * 100 + 'px',
      'height:' + Math.random() * 100 + 'px','position: absolute'
    ];
    // Join the attributes together with semi-colon and write the div to the document
    // Note: Document write happens at the place where the script is executed
    document.write('<div style="' + attr.join(';')  +'"></div>');
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The attribute array was definitely a huge help, I was stumped on how to go about plugging in variables. Thanks for that!